# How do you decrease the amount of Vertices in an object?

Tags: modeling

Let's say I used the subsurf mod to 5 and applied it, but later want to it not subsurf-ed, let's assume that i didnt do a save either.

Comment: Try *Decimate Modifier*.

Comment: Never apply modifiers unless strictly necessary, and if you do save a copy of the original .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is a way to restore the original mesh (with the exact topology) after applying *subsurf modifier*. What you can do is use an ***Un-Subdivide*** option of the **Decimate Modifier** (expect some loss in detail though). General rule is if your applied subsurf level was set to 2 you set the unsubdivide level to 4 etc. In my case I set the *Un-Subdivide* level to *10* on a model with the level *5* *subsurf* applied.
[image]
[image]
***Note:*** After appling *Decimate* modifier you may go to *Edit Mode*, select all the vertices (<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to get rid of some tris to make the topology even more similar to the original mesh.

Comment: Thank you...i did saw that modifier, but never knew how to use it...thanks again..

Comment: you can try to project your decimated mesh onto your lvl 5 subdiv mesh to regains some of that lost detail